# Sending CiviCRM outgoing SMS on a case

Tags: civicase, sms

It doesn't appear that CiviCRM can send an outbound SMS via an activity on a case. The outbound SMS activity shows as a normal activity, rather than the send SMS screen. Is this normal / expected behaviour and are there work arounds to support SMS on a case?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably just never come up. There is special handling in the code for Email to make that work. It would need something similar.

However, by somewhat of a fluke, you can use the subject line feature for activities to send a regular SMS the normal way and have it filed on a case. Where it says "Name the SMS", include `[case #1234]` somewhere in that field, where 1234 is the appropriate case id. Then it will file it on the case.

Comment: Thanks @demerit. It just seems bizarre that the outbound SMS activity wouldn't function the same on a case activity as a normal activity. Thanks for the suggestion about adding the case ID, as this might prove useful in scoping a work around.